# Не работает проверка на одинаковые числа в массиве(си)

Tags: c, массивы, проверка

Должны удалиться одинаковые числа в массиве. Например, если массив {3, 3, 3}, то должно остаться {3}. По задумке, создается копия массива, сравниваются элементы копии с не копией, и одинаковые элементы приравниваются 0 и, соответственно, исчезают. Но почему-то не работает.
Код:

```
for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        copyC[i] = C[i];
    }

    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < k;i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            if (copyC[i] = C[j]) {
                count++;
                if (count > 1)
                {
                    C[j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: А вы не присваивайте в `if`, а сравнивайте...

Comment: Не вижу связи между "одинаковые элементы приравниваются 0" и "исчезают". С чего вы это взяли?

Comment: @Эникейщик мне нужно как-то уменьшить размер массива, предполагалось, если занулить элементы, то размер уменьшится, но уже вижу, что не работает. Не подскажите, как все таки это сделать? Массив одномерный, статический

Comment: 2 ошибки вижу, во-первых в if нужно сравнение "==", а во-вторых, во втором for нужно идти не от 0, а от (i + 1)

Comment: @Harry может стоит написать вопрос и дать на него ответ, а остальные вопросы закрывать как дубликаты?

Comment: @Danis Мне уже не раз говорили на мете, что главное - побольше вопросов, и что даже самый тупой вопрос имеет право на ответ... Я уже перестал с этим спорить. В конце концов, любой самый интеллектуальный ресурс со временем деградирует до... Так почему ruSO должен быть исключением? Удивляет другое - количество людей, которые не стесняются такие вопросы задавать :)

Comment: Ха, только что уже прочел [один комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1224269/%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-c#comment2143147_1224269) к другому вопросу - прямо сюда годится, ничего не меняя ))

Answer (score 1):

Оператор сравнения `==`, а не `=`.

Comment: также `int count = 0;` надо поставит между двумя `for`